# Searching using UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I have a search bar added to the navigation bar. When the user types a word and clicks the search button (keyboard) I need to display results in the table related to the search.

When I click "Search", I get blank records (it actually goes inside the `if` condition in the `searchBarSearchButtonClicked:` method and adds the animal object too). I think there's a problem in

```
[mutableArray addObject:animal];
...
self.animalArray = mutableArray;    
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

My complete code is as follows.

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    [self.mutableArray removeAllObjects];
    for (Animal *animal in self.animalArray) {
        if ([[animal nameOfAnimal] isEqualToString:[searchBar text]] ) {                
            [mutableArray addObject:animal];
        }
    }
    self.animalArray = mutableArray;    
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {        
        Animal *animal = [self.animalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        
        cell = [[Cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                           reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.nameofani.text=animal.nameOfAnimal;   
        cell.oriofani.text=animal.originOfAnimal;  
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
self.animalArray = [mutableArray copy];
```

Comment: Still i get blank records. When i print the count of self.animalArray it gives the result as 1. So there is a match found and for some reason its not getting shown in the table. Help ?

Comment: Did you try  NSLog(@" self.animalArray = %@", self.animalArray); to see what the match is?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you implement `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` correctly, returning `[self.animalArray count]` for the search results table view.